# Magento Product Export Issue 1.9.3.6

Tags: php, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am getting PHP Fatal Error while exporting products to CSV

> [01-Jan-2020 10:05:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File '/home/xyz/public_html/abc/media/catalog/category/' does not exists.' in /home/xyz/public_html/abc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php:96

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/xyz/public_html/abc/get.php(205): Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/home/customerd...')
#1 /home/xyz/public_html/abc/get.php(165): sendFile('/home/customerd...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/xyz/public_html/abc/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96
[01-Jan-2020 10:06:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in /home/xyz/public_html/abc/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 948
```

Comment: Please add the relevent code section when you ask question about certain code throwing error.

Comment: Sure @AshishModi. can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: @AmanKalra you need to add in the question the code in `/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 948`

Answer (score 0):

In that line in base code:

`$dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];`

I guess the `$dataRow` or `$stockItemRows[$productId]` is an unsupported data type for addition. Eg: array, empty, null...

Try to debug it writing to log the values of `$dataRow` and `$stockItemRows[$productId]` data before the addition to see what happens.